# Upgrading .NET Core from 2.1 to 2.2 results in SQL connection errors

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I had a working API site running on IIS. Then I upgraded my solution from .NET Core 2.1 to 2.2, and I'm getting the following error now:

```
    "ExceptionDetail": {
        "Type": "System.InvalidOperationException",
        "HResult": -2146233079,
        "Message": "An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure()' to the 'UseSqlServer' call.",
        "Source": "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer",
        "InnerException": {
            "Data": {
                "HelpLink.ProdName": "Microsoft SQL Server",
                "HelpLink.EvtSrc": "MSSQLServer",
                "HelpLink.EvtID": "10060",
                "HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl": "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink",
                "HelpLink.LinkId": "20476"
            },
            "HResult": -2146232060,
            "Message": "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)",
            "Source": "Core .Net SqlClient Data Provider",
            "InnerException": {
                "HResult": -2147467259,
                "Message": "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond",
                "Source": null,
                "NativeErrorCode": 10060,
                "ErrorCode": -2147467259,
                "Type": "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception"
            },
            "Errors": [
                {
                    "Source": "Core .Net SqlClient Data Provider",
                    "Number": 10060,
                    "State": 0,
                    "Class": 20,
                    "Server": "",
                    "Message": "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)",
                    "Procedure": null,
                    "LineNumber": 0
                }
            ],
            "ClientConnectionId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "Class": 20,
            "LineNumber": 0,
            "Number": 10060,
            "Procedure": null,
            "Server": "",
            "State": 0,
            "ErrorCode": -2146232060,
            "Type": "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException"
        }
```

I reverted back to my old 2.1 code, and it worked. I also published a self-contained solution and still getting the same error. I also set `.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)`;

My Service project references the Application project which references the database project, and here are the project files:

Services:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;Production</Configurations>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <NoWarn>1701;1702;IDE0021</NoWarn>
    <OutputPath></OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\CaseManagement.Service.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1591</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Shared\netcoreapp2.1\**" />
    <Content Remove="Shared\netcoreapp2.1\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Shared\netcoreapp2.1\**" />
    <None Remove="Shared\netcoreapp2.1\**" />
  </ItemGroup>



  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations" Version="4.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CaseManagement.Application\CaseManagement.Application.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CaseManagement.Infrustructure.Log\CaseManagement.Infrastructure.Log.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="appsettings.Development.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="appsettings.Production.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="appsettings.Staging.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="Properties\launchSettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Application:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;Production</Configurations>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <NoWarn>1701;1702;IDE0021;1591</NoWarn>
    <DocumentationFile>obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\CaseManagement.Application.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <OutputPath></OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CaseManagement.Core\CaseManagement.Core.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CaseManagement.Infrustructure.Database\CaseManagement.Infrastructure.Database.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CaseManagement.Infrustructure.Log\CaseManagement.Infrastructure.Log.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.core\2.1.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\Users\dinua\.nuget\packages\swashbuckle.aspnetcore.annotations\4.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\Users\dinua\.nuget\packages\swashbuckle.aspnetcore.swagger\4.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\Users\dinua\.nuget\packages\swashbuckle.aspnetcore.swaggergen\4.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Database:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;Production</Configurations>
    <AssemblyName>CaseManagement.Infrastructure.Database</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>CaseManagement.Infrastructure.Database</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Repo\Shared\" />
    <Folder Include="Sql\StoredProcedures\" />
    <Folder Include="Sql\Tables\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CaseManagement.Infrustructure.Log\CaseManagement.Infrastructure.Log.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System">
      <HintPath>System</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Not sure what else I can do.

Comment: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. -> it says i can't find db you give me invalid connection string. So you can look your data context class' constructor. Check your ConnectionString true or false;

Comment: I double checked that. The connection string is correct. I also replaced it with the working version (2.1).

Comment: Is the db context has empty constructor ?

Comment: Yes, it's empty.

Comment: I also followed this Microsoft article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Also, one thing to note, it does work on my local machine using the same settings.

Comment: @Batuhan, you were correct, although I'm not sure why. When I logged the connection string, I saw it was trying to connect to a production database, but I don't understand where it got the connection string from. I have multiple appsetting files, one for each environment. So the first question is: Why did it pick up the production.appsettings file. The second question is, even after updating the connection string in the file and re-starting IIS and the app pool, it still read production, a connection string that is not found in any file or in my code.

Comment: I suspect that when I publish, it adds the connection string somewhere, and by making sure that I point to QA did the trick.

Comment: can you share location of masked connection string and your startup.cs ?

Comment: Or you can try to run your project in development mode ?